# How to add a profile with a fieldset that accepts one or more entries for event registrations

Tags: drupal, custom-fields, online-registration

I'm not sure that this is possible but here goes:

I have a requirement to collect data from Event Registrants of University Programs that they have undertaken and the years of study they have undertaken. This is not limited to a single entry for the program and each program entry can have 1 or more years of study.

So an Entry could look as follows:

**Program of Study:** Basket Weaving

**Years of Study:**

- 1972
- 1973
- 1974

Ideally I would want to have multiple fieldsets of the Program of Study and Years so the registrant could list one or more programs they undertook and the years they undertook for it.

In that case it would look like:

**Program of Study:** Basket Weaving

**Years of Study:**

- 1972
- 1973
- 1974

**Program of Study:** Advance Basket Weaving

**Years of Study:**

- 1982
- 1983
- 1984

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use Activities. Set up a custom Activity with the required fields for Program, Year etc

Another approach might be Multiple Record custom field

Comment: Hi Peter. I'll try that idea of a custom activity and see if it works. That would be awesome if it did. I tried with a Multiple Record custom field and although it allows me to create multiple within a contact record, I can't do it from an event signup page. Cheers, Andrew.

Comment: how did you get on? would be good to get a +1 on here (StackExchange otherwise keeps promoting this as a Q with no accepted answers)

Comment: Hi Peter, I'm still looking for a usable method. Neither worked for my use case. Multiple Field Records only work when you're administering a contact's record, whereas in my use case, I wanted the event registrants to be able to add them. I ended up limiting it to 3 records and used jQuery to expose them as needed. Not ideal but it gets the job done. I'm happy for StackExchange to keep promoting it. It seems like a useful option.

Comment: I would still most likely be tackling this via Activities (with custom fields) and webform_civicrm

Comment: Hi Peter. That might be the best method to deal with this. This is a D7  site and we aren't using Webform CiviCRM with it so next year I'll be doing a Drupal 9 migration. I think I will dig further into refining it then. Thanks, Andrew.

Comment: understood. if you can give this Answer a tick then it makes SE happier